# CmisConnectionException with CMIS Workbench when connecting to SharePoint FBA site

Tags: forms-authentication, sub-site, cmis

While using [CMIS Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html), I got the below issue just after clicking on "Load Repository".

I am not able to see documents from the site or its subsites. Please help me if any configuration is needed on the SharePoint side.

[image: Not able to open the site using cmis work Bench.got the below issue while click on Load Repository. Please help]

Comment: I'm afraid the question is more targeted to the tool than to SharePoint, it could make it difficult for you to find the answer here. I would throw out a hook at the tools forums as well to increase the chances :)

Comment: @MHeld: CMIS Workbench is the reference tool for testing CMIS servers. When CMIS Workbench fails to connect, you can be sure there is a server-side problem (in this case most probably a SharePoint misconfiguration).

Comment: Sudhir, please set the parameter `-Dcmis.workbench.acceptSelfSignedCertificates=true` in your `workbench.bat`, as suggested in the error message, and try again. Probably the underlying error will appear then.

Answer (score 2):

The **Basic Authentication** must be enabled for the web application to can connect to the CMIS!

For more details, check

- [SharePoint 2016: Configure Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS)](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/10/25/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis/)

Comment: HI,Still i have Forbidden issue in ViewLog file while click on Sync the Document library where that site having FBA implemented.Please help

Comment: Test the API with postman to make sure that the issue is not related to the authentication as I mentioned at https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis/